# How to detect if an element is in the viewport without scroll event in Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to know if it exists a way to detect if an element is in the viewport without scroll event in Javascript / jQuery ?

In fact, I would like to trigger a function when a certain element is visible by the viewport but... without the scroll event. Actually, my page uses the "you scroll one time and it takes you to the next screen" system. That's why my function isn't triggered...

Here is an example of my page :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CBsed06QSxxCw5wy6N-DzTj46I9K-tl/view?usp=sharing

I've already tried the jquery.visible library and seen for other event listeners. I tried my code in a normal page with a normal scroll effect, and it works fine, but not with my actual scroll effect.

Here is what my current code looks like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    // doesn't work
    jQuery(window).scroll(function()
    {
        myFunction();
    });

});
```

Thank you !

Comment: You need to use the scroll event to know when the viewport has moved. Unless you only ever want to check the viewport when the page loads, then there's no real alternative to using scroll. I'm sure it can work for you, but without knowing what you're doing and what issue you face, we can't really help

Comment: I guess so too, but the fact that I scroll just one time isn't spotted as a scroll by the scroll function...

Comment: what do you mean 1 scroll is not detected ? and how could javaScript know you want to check if the element is inside the viewport on scroll if you don't use the scroll event ?

Comment: Thanks anyway @Rory, I'll try to figure that out :)

Comment: @Mihai Well, I just need to scroll one time for the screen to scroll itself to the next part of the screen, and apparently the scroll event listener doesn't get that I'm scrolling because my function isn't triggered...

Comment: which is your `myFunction()` . Because if you scroll, anything inside the scroll function should be triggered. Did you try to put a `console.log('test')` inside that scroll function ? does that get printed in the console ?

Comment: Of course, I tried with a console.log('test') and it didn't work... And as I said, the function is well triggered on a page where the scroll is "normal" scroll, so I don't think the problem is my function

Comment: I figured out that it doesn't work because the overflow (which is on the html tag) has the property hidden.